# Create website in malayalam language

Tags: html, css, utf-8

It's my first work in web-designing. I have to develop a website having contents in Malayalam and menus in English. Anyone please help me in doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a URL of your best effort so far, and explain what the problem with it is.

Comment: I searched all over the internet. But I can't get clearly in any of the post of how to do. In my <head></head> section I just included that utf-8 encoding. After that what i have to do. Thaks for immediate response

Comment: You can try [http://translate.google.com/?hl=fr](http://translate.google.com/?hl=fr) to translate languange.
or you can try using particular fonts.

Comment: Hi Jukka,   I am working in localhost only. So I can't post the URl

Comment: Then how can we know what you need help with? Please edit your question to indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. Rember this is a site for programming questions.

Answer (score 8):

For Multiple language support in websites you need to take care of three things basically.

**1. Meta tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**2. Font-face**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Malayalam';
    src: url('../fonts/meera.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/meera.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/meera.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/meera.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/meera.svg#Malayalam') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can use [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) fontface generator if you just have the .ttf file

**3. Doctype**

If you use HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` it won't work sometimes.

Use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. You specified src:url('../fonts/meera.svg#MyriadProBold') format('svg'); I know the other formats.   Thanks,                                                               Siva.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you want to know how to get the characters to show in your HTML, since your question is not too clear. In order for the browser to correctly display Malayalam characters, you need to encode your web page in UTF-8. In addition, due to browser quirks, you need to declare the UTF-8 encoding in your header content type, or some browsers try to send HTML escaped characters instead.

If you are using HTML 5: `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Otherwise: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. This would go in your `<head>...</head>` tags.

Comment: Hi,I included that meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> in my html.After that what I have to do to work with that. Whether there is a need of download the font or not. I don't know to to proceed the next step

Comment: While UTF-8 is probably the practical choice, you don’t *have* to use it. The use of `meta` to declare encoding does not depend on browser quirks but on the possible scenario that the character encoding is not declared in HTTP headers.

Comment: If characters other than what the browser assumes is page encoding are sent, HTML-escaped character may/will be displayed.

Comment: @sivasangari -- there are two options for displaying the fonts. One is to use Google's translate API. The other is to embed the fonts in your CSS using `font-face`.

Comment: HI Roddy, I already tried  to embed the fonts in CSS using font-face property. My code was 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en">  
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">                                                     
@font-face
{ 
font-family:Meera; 
src:url(Data/Sites/..../meera.ttf);
} 
.malayalam
{
font-family:Meera; 
}                                                                 
</head> 
<body>

Comment: I want to create that website like http://indiavisiontv.com